# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS: Is my code locked in a loop?

Tags: javascript, redirect, tableau-api

I'm trying to work through the Tableau .js API tutorial, and immediately I got stuck with a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error when I tried to use the online example with a chart I posted to our server.

I am pretty new to this work, so I thought I'd offer the relevant snippet and see if you can spot anything that's likely to generate re-directs in a loop.

Some notes: "" is just a dummy substituion.  It is not the problem.

Here is the code.  Thanks for any advice!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <head> 
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="https://online.tableausoftware.com/javascripts/api/tableau_v8.js"></script>
    </head>        
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initializeViz() {
              var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz");
              var url = "http://<PATH TO CHART>";
              var options = {
                width: '1200px',
                height: '600px',
              };
              viz = new tableauSoftware.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options);
            }     
         </script>
        <a href="#" onclick="$('#tableauViz').html(''); initializeViz()">visualize</a>
        <div class id ="tableauViz"></div>
    </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's nothing to do with the code.  I found that it's a credentialing issue.  I don't know much about security and log-in resolution, but perhaps this will help someone: I resolved the issue by FIRST logging into Tableau in advance, so that my credentials were already established for that session.  Then when I reloaded the above code, it worked.  So I infer that I have to work out the credential pass-through issues in advance if this code is going to work well for other users.  Anyway, that's the solution path I'm trying next.  HTH