# Loading embedded tableau without manual efforts - Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Checked from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25896838/8595958) answer that, in case of ***tableau redirected you too many times***, we first have to login to the tableau manually so that the logged in session in stored and then refresh the HTML page in which the tableau is embedded to load the tableau in HTML.

This seems to be little absurd/inconvenient. Is there a way to achieve that without any such efforts?

Check on other sites which says to clear cache/change content settings etc. My concern is that, when my application (which contains this embedded tableau) is hosted in a server, it would required all the application users to do all these manual processes. Which is not recommended.

Kindly help on a suitable suggestion on this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will help someone in the near future.

The only thing to check on encountering this error is to know, *whether you use a domain server/you have created your tableau credentials with a domain server*.

The generic https://tableau/views/.. URL will not work, since the UI in which you are trying to embed the code, will hold the credentials that belongs to your domain and not the common domain of tableau. So, the tableau will be retrying you credentials in its common domain.

**What you have to do is to concatenate the tableau with your domain like**: https://tableau.ent.domain.lld.com/views/..

This will use your credentials to the tableau used on your domain server.

Hope this will help.